# How to create separate DB for every company in django?

Tags: python, django

I'm going to create Saas CRM system and now i'm trying to design a database architecture. Using separate DB for each company seems to me most efficient. But in this case new database must be created automatically after user's registration.  How can i implement this on django? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: *"Using separate DB for each company seems to me most efficient"* — Why so? It may be "efficient" in some respects, but creates a lot of new headaches in others…

Comment: Because if the size of the database grows, its performance will decrease.

Comment: Will it now? Do you have factual data for that? Have you tested it? With what size databases? Have you optimised everything you can about the database structure, indexes and your queries before coming to that conclusion?

Comment: I don't believe that for example searching a table with a billion rows will be performed at the same speed as searching a table with a hundred rows

Comment: 1) Depends on your indices. 2) Slower doesn't necessarily mean *too slow*. 3) Will you *really* get to a billion rows in any finite time, or will your project just die before? If you do get enough customers to fill a billion rows, your project is probably successful enough so you can refactor it then.

Comment: I think that the correct architecture of the project should be developed at the very beginning. And a billion rows is not so much, as 2-3 small companies can contribute as much data.

Comment: *If* you are preparing to handle a billion rows, you *definitely* want to run some tests with artificial data that confirms your suspicion and gives you actual data to base your design decisions on…

Comment: I think that's what I needed: https://github.com/agiliq/building-multi-tenant-applications-with-django

Comment: Recenlty, I have been createing an application with Django which needs tenant data separation. I havn't made the decesion yet about the level of data separation. But: I have came across a book which could help you explore the possible opportunities:
[Introduction to multi tenant applications](https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-multi-tenant/en/latest/introduction.html) I think what you looking for is the section: "Shared database with shared schema"